# /usr/libexec/java_home Filter By JDK

Tags: java, bash, macos

In my MacOS i am using something like the below to set java on my

```sh
setJava() {
    version=$@
    echo "Setting JAVA to " $version
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $version)
    echo "JAVA_HOME:" $JAVA_HOME
    java -version
}
```

That works fine, but what i would like to achieve is choose a JDK not by the version, but by the JVM release itself, like Zulu, OpenJDK, Graal etc.

If i run

```sh
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

i am getting

```sh
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    12.0.1, x86_64: "AdoptOpenJDK 12"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_212, x86_64:  "GraalVM CE 19.0.0" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-19.0.0/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_163-zulu-8.28.0.1, x86_64:    "Zulu 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_161, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Is there any way to parameterize the above script so that /usr/libexec/java_home returns me the JDK of the JDK that i would like to use?

Comment: What is wrong with parsing the output shown here?

Comment: you mean something like grepping for a pattern? Yeah, i thought of that. I was hoping there is a more elegant and less error prone way of doing so.

Comment: Use regexps to look for X, Y: "Z"   Q and then examine Z closer.